# Python - counting sign changes

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers I am reading left to right. Anytime I encounter a sign change when reading the sequence I want to count it.

```
X = [-3,2,7,-4,1,-1,1,6,-1,0,-2,1] 
X = [-, +, +, -, +, -, +, +, -, -,-,+]
```

So, in this list there are 8 sign changes.

When Item `[0]` (in this case -3) is negative it is considered a sign change. Also, any 0 in the list is considered `[-]`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it helps anyone answering, here's a Haskell solution: `signChanges xs = sum $ zipWith (\x y -> if (x>0) == (y>0) then 0 else 1) (1:xs) xs`

Comment: Here is a link for those looking for [**a solution where zero is handled as no change**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40804510/2192488).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to count the groups of positive and non-positive numbers:

```
>>> x = [-3,2,7,-4,1,-1,1,6,-1,0,-2,1] 

>>> import itertools
>>> len(list(itertools.groupby(x, lambda x: x > 0)))
```

Result:

```
8
```

In your question you state that you want:

- to count the changes, not the groups
- to count an extra change if the first element is not positive.

You can do this either by testing the first element directly and adjusting the result:

```
>>> len(list(itertools.groupby(x, lambda x: x > 0))) - (x[0] > 0)
```

or by prepending a positive number to the input before doing the grouping then subtracting 1 from the result:

```
>>> len(list(itertools.groupby(itertools.chain([1], x), lambda x: x > 0))) - 1
```

Watch out if your input list could by empty - the former solution will raise an exception.

Comment: +1 because I wrote the same, except it looks like `len(list(itertools.groupby(x > 0 for x in X)))`

Comment: `for x in X` seriously? That's worse than `for a in b`

Answer (score 7):

```
X = [-3,2,7,-4,1,-1,1,6,-1,0,-2,1]

last_sign = 1
sign_changes = 0

for x in X:
    if x == 0:
        sign = -1
    else:
        sign = x / abs(x)

    if sign == -last_sign:
        sign_changes = sign_changes + 1
        last_sign = sign

print sign_changes
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using fold, have fun figuring it out:

```
def lolwut((x,c), y):
    return (y, c+(x^y))

print reduce( lolwut ,(x > 0 for x in X), (True,0)) # 8
print reduce( lolwut ,(x > 0 for x in X), (False,0)) # 7
```

Answer (score 1):

For integers, `(a^b) < 0` if signs of *a* and *b* are different.

```
def countSignChanges(seq):
    # make sure 0's are treated as negative
    seq = [-1 if not x else x for x in seq]

    # zip with leading 1, so that opening negative value is 
    # treated as sign change
    return sum((a^b)<0 for a,b in zip([1]+seq, seq))


X = [-3,2,7,-4,1,-1,1,6,-1,0,-2,1]
print countSignChanges(X)
```

gives the desired answer, *8*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it without loops... It should be much faster for large data ;) (however, because of the numpy etc, will not be as efficient for small lists- and it will be much better for numpy array than lists for obvious reasons - you can even drop the conversion...)

```
x = np.array([-3,2,7,-4,1,-1,1,6,-1,0,-2,1])
positive= x>0
count = np.logical_xor(positive[1:],positive[:-1]).sum()
count += not(positive[0])
print count
```

returns 8

Xor returns true if the two booleans are different ( from + to - ) and is pretty fast. There is one problem with the code: if something goes to exactly 0 from the positive sign, it will count as crossing. This is exactly what you ask in your question though since you represented 0 as '-'.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a much simpler option is to use:

```
K = np.sum(np.abs(np.diff(x>0)))
```

which also gives the same result without complex computations.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [-3,2,7,-4,1,-1,1,6,-1,0,-2,1]
# could be replaced by     signs = [x > 0 for x in numbers]
# but this methods gives us nice minus and plus signs
signs = map(lambda x: "+" if x > 0 else "-", numbers)

# zip(…) creates the pairs, each pair that has different signs
# adds one to "count"
count = sum(1 for x,y in zip(signs[:-1], signs[1:]) if x != y)
```

-> 7

For your additional requirement, that a negative number at the start of the list should be considered another change, just add a positive number to your list.

If you're dealing with huge lists, consider using generators. (izip, tee, …)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't been convinced to read the itertools documentation yet:

```
def pairs(iterable):
    'iter -> (iter0, iter1), (iter1, iter2), (iter3, iter4), ...'
    from itertools import izip, tee
    first, second = tee(iterable)
    second.next()
    return izip(first, second)

def sign_changes(l):
    result = 0
    if l and l[0]<=0: result += 1
    result += sum(1 for a,b in pairs(l) if b*a<=0 and (a!=0 or b!=0))
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Input = [-1, 2, 3, -4, 5, -6, 7, 8, -9, 10, -11, 12] 

for i in range(len(Input)):
    if(Input[i]<1):
        Input[i]=0
    else:
        Input[i]=1

print(Input) #[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

count=0
check=Input[0]
for i in range(len(Input)-1):

    if check != Input[i + 1]:
        count+=1
        check=Input[i+1]


print(count) #9
```

Comment: Maybe print count-1 to match op expected answer

Comment: There are 9 sign changes in the list so 9 is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using element-wise multiplication with the shifted array and signbit should be the fastest:

```
X = np.array([-3,2,7,-4,1,-1,1,6,-1,0,-2,1])
sign_changes = np.sum(np.signbit(X[1:]*X[:-1]))
```

Counting the first value as a change if it is negative:

```
if X[0] < 0: sign_changes += 1
```

Because 0 is neither negative nor positive it can be replaced with a random negative number to be counted as a negative.