# np.diff(np.signbit()) no longer finds zero crossings, better way?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29674950/3904031) is what I'm looking for, but since boolean subtraction has been depreciated it no longer works. Is there a better way?

```
A   = np.array([[-2, -1,  1], 
                [-1,  0,  1], 
                [-1,  1,  2]], dtype=float)

zcs = np.diff(np.signbit(A), axis=1)     # find zero crossings in each row - now fails
```

generates:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/david/Documents/wow.py", line 4, in <module>
    zcs = np.diff(np.signbit(A), axis=1)     # now fails
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1926, in diff
    return a[slice1]-a[slice2]

TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is deprecated, use the bitwise_xor, the `^` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.
```

Comment: Works without error for me. What's your NumPy version?

Comment: @Divakar '1.13.0'

Comment: Upgrade to 1.14.0?

Comment: @Divakar OK I just found/tried an Anaconda installation and indeed it works fine, problem solved. What to do in this case? Would you like to post a short answer?

Comment: Nah, I am good :) This  post isn't adding anything new, so maybe delete this one.

Comment: @Divakar it seems you are! I quickly checked the [release notes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.14.0-notes.rst) didn't see anything obvious but did find out support for Python 2 is ending which is good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I guess could be useful for people stuck with old versions. Take your call. Seems trivial to me.

Comment: In any case, `zcs = np.diff(np.signbit(A).astype(int), axis=1)` should work.

Comment: @DanielF I was using signbit based on the linked answer *using* `numpy.signbit()` *is a little bit quicker than* `numpy.sign()`, but certainly recasting would work immediately in a pinch, I hadn't thought of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently fixed in 1.14.0, but as a quick fix explicit type casting:

```
zcs = np.diff(np.signbit(A).astype(int), axis=1)
```

should work.