# Finding the zeroes of a position vector

Tags: python

For my dynamics course I am tasked with writing a python code that will plot the trajectory of a position vector from when it starts on the ground to when it lands on the ground. I currently have my code create a linear space from the two zero values that I calculated by hand, but I want to code that in. Because I also need to create velocity vectors on the trajectory, I have the position vector broken into its x and y components. I have looked into [xlim](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843017/efficiently-detect-sign-changes-in-python) thread, but couldn't figure out how to implement them. I'm fairly new to python and coding in general, so I'm still trying to learn how things work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#creates a function that returns the x component
def re10(x):
    r1 =  0.05*x
    return r1

#creates a function that returns the y component
def re20(x):
    r2 =  -4.91*(x**2) + 30*x + 100
    return r2


#Calculates the two zeroes of the trajectory
tmin = (-30 + np.sqrt(30**2 -4*-4.91*100))/(2*-4.91)
tmax = (-30 - np.sqrt(30**2 -4*-4.91*100))/(2*-4.91)


#Initializing time space
t = np.linspace(tmin, tmax, 100)


#Plot
plt.plot(re10(t), re20(t)) #(x, y)
```

Comment: why you don't use [simpy](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ? Python and Symbolic equations are really powerful when used together!

Comment: I have never heard of simpy.

Comment: give me a couple secs :)

Comment: My mistake, you can use `numpy` to find zeroes of your equation, and you actually already have it based from your code, so just use np.roots to find your zeroes!

Comment: Some unasked-for coding advice: I strongly suggest you avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) in your code. For instance, put `g=9.81` somewhere at the top then use `0.5*g` instead of `4.91` whenever you need it. This will help you (and others) considerably when reading the code some time after writing it.

Comment: The reason I use -4.91 is because the given position vector is: r(t) = (0.05*t)x_1 + (-4.91t^2 + 30t + 100)x_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily find the zeroes of a funtion using `numpy` library.

First, install it. Open a cmd console and write `pip install numpy`.
Then, write this code in your script:

```
import numpy
re20 = [-4.91, 30, 100]
zeroes = numpy.roots(coeff)
print(zeroes[0])
print(zeroes[1])
```

As you will see when running the script from console (or you IDE), `numpy.roots(function)` will return you the zeroes of your function, as an array. 
That is why you use the `[]` operator to access each one of them (take note that in programming, an array's first element will be at index `0`).

To use it directly into your code, you can do:

```
tmin = zeroes[0]
tmax = zeroes[1]
```

`Simpy` is for symbolic operations, it is pretty powerful, but you don't need it for this, my mistake.

Hope you have fun with Python, it's a cool language !