# How to get the second derivative/dip from the graph or generate the best eps value

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, statistics, dbscan

Dataset is below

```
 ,id,revenue ,profit
0,101,779183,281257
1,101,144829,838451
2,101,766465,757565
3,101,353297,261071
4,101,1615461,275760
5,101,246731,949229
6,101,951518,301016
7,101,444669,430583
```

Code is below

```
import pandas as pd;
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv',index_col=None)
df1 = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)
dbsc = DBSCAN(eps = 2.5, min_samples = 20).fit(df1)
labels = dbsc.labels_
```

My shape of df is 1999

I got the dip value `eps` value from the below method, from graph its clear that eps=2.5

[image]

Below is the method to find the best eps value

```
ns = 5
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=ns).fit(df3)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(df3)
distanceDec = sorted(distances[:,ns-1], reverse=True)
plt.plot(indices[:,0], distanceDec)
#plt.plot(list(range(1,2000)), distanceDec)
```

- How to find the dip in the graph automatically by the system mean best `eps` is expected out? without looking in to graph, my system has to tell best `eps`

Comment: There is this paper that introduces an algorithm that automatically assigns values to eps and min_samples : https://www.ijisae.org/IJISAE/article/view/649/pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the precise *y* value of the inflection point appearing in your *ε(x)* plot (it should be around 2.0), right?

If this is correct, being *ε(x)* your curve, the problem is reduced to:

1. Compute the second derivative of your curve: *ε''(x)*.
2. Find the zero (or zeroes) of such second derivative: *x0*.
3. Recover the optimized *ε* value, just by plugging the zero into your curve: *ε(x0)*.

Here I attach my answer, based in this two other Stack Overflow answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26042315/10489040 (Compute derivative of an array)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3843124/10489040 (Find zero in array)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generating x data range from -1 to 4 with a step of 0.01
x = np.arange(-1, 4, 0.01)

# Simulating y data with an inflection point as y(x) = x³ - 5x² + 2x
y = x**3 - 5*x**2 + 2*x

# Plotting your curve
plt.plot(x, y, label="y(x)")

# Computing y 1st derivative of your curve with a step of 0.01 and plotting it
y_1prime = np.gradient(y, 0.01)
plt.plot(x, y_1prime, label="y'(x)")

# Computing y 2nd derivative of your curve with a step of 0.01 and plotting it
y_2prime = np.gradient(y_1prime, 0.01)
plt.plot(x, y_2prime, label="y''(x)")

# Finding the index of the zero (or zeroes) of your curve
x_zero_index = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(y_2prime)))[0]

# Finding the x value of the zero of your curve
x_zero_value = x[x_zero_index][0]

# Finding the y value corresponding to the x value of the zero
y_zero_value = y[x_zero_index][0]

# Reporting
print(f'The inflection point of your curve is {y_zero_value:.3f}.')
```

[image]

In any case, keep in mind that the inflection point (around 2.0) does not match with the "dip" point appearing around 2.5.