# Get all zeroes from matplotlib graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

How could I get a list of all the zeroes of a matplotlib graph? By zeroes I mean every coordinate where the y-value of my function is at 0 (very close to zero also works for what I'm trying to accomplish). My code and the graph it generates are down below.

**THE .WAV FILE:** https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11nE0nyd9UPViicSIKNeiBqSNbdWGRbIl?usp=sharing

**MY CODE:**

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

samplerate, data = wavfile.read(r'C:\Users\jack_l\Downloads\louduntitled.wav')
length = data.shape[0] / samplerate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
time = np.linspace(0., length, data.shape[0])
plt.plot(time, data[:, 1], label="Right channel")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.show()
```

**GRAPH:**

[image: Graph]

Comment: The x values are 0 at exactly one point: x=0. I assume you mean the y values, but if you have the data, you don't need the plot which is just a single "view" of the data.

Comment: erip Actually I think there isn't any 0 in his data, he kinda want an interpolation

Comment: Yes, the best you can talk about for discretized continuous data is ranges where a 0 appears which makes the problem slightly easier: for each window defined by your timestep, check if the sign changes between the start and stop.

Comment: @erip You're correct – I meant I want the coordinates where the y-value is equal to 0 (or very close to 0). How could I get what I'm looking for just using the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to find all times where the y-value is zero.

What about finding [zero-crossings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3843124/4166745) of the array `data[:, 1]` (here `a`), and use the returned indices to find the interpolated time values where y-value is zero.

CODE

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

# load data
samplerate, data = wavfile.read(r'C:\Users\jack_l\Downloads\louduntitled.wav')
length = data.shape[0] / samplerate
time = np.linspace(0., length, data.shape[0])

a = data[:, 1] # here put your data
zc_idxs = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(a)))[0] # indices of element before zero crossing
t_zero = []
for zc_i in zc_idxs: # interpolate each zero crossing
    t1 = time[zc_i]
    t2 = time[zc_i + 1]
    a1 = a[zc_i]
    a2 = a[zc_i + 1]
    t_zero.append(t1 + (0 - a1) * ((t2 - t1) / (a2 - a1)))

plt.plot(time, a, label="Right channel")
plt.plot(t_zero, np.zeros((len(t_zero), 1)), 'o')
```

Comment: How would I input my data from my .wav into this? Sorry I'm new to matplotlib.

Comment: simply put your data in to my dummy variable a: `a = data[:,1]` (you can read `a` as amplitude)

Comment: Works perfectly thank you (only thing is 2nd last line should be ```plt.plot(time, a, label="Right channel")``` instead of ```plt.plot(t, a, label="Right channel")```)

Answer (score 0):

We can't access to your data, so I used the *cos* function to have a similar shape.

Here is my code that perform a linear interpolation (there's a small error due to the non-linear behavior of the *cos* function)

```
import numpy as np

n = 2000
x = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
y = np.cos(x)

res = []
is_positive = y[0] > 0
for i in range(n):
    if y[i] == 0:
        res.append(x[i])
    elif (is_positive and y[i] < 0) or (not is_positive and y[i] > 0):
        x_gap = x[i] - x[i-1]
        coef_gap = y[i]/(y[i] - y[i-1])
        res.append(x[i] + x_gap*coef_gap)
        is_positive = not is_positive
        
analytic_res = [i*np.pi/2 for i in range(1,6,2)]

print(res)
print(analytic_res)
```

Output :

```
[1.5807794610537442, 4.722328378160516, 7.863877295269648]
[1.5707963267948966, 4.71238898038469, 7.853981633974483]
```

NB : if the very first value is zero, the code could have a weird behavior

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this. I also added a link to the file I'm using so there's access to the data.