# How to obtain all possible values using interpolate of scipy?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I'm trying to identify all the y-axis values when my data passes through zero on the x-axis. Using scipy's interpolation function it only shows me the last value, why? or Can anyone help me to deal with this issue?

This is my code:

```
x = <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1shJtrg9orwLFm9Da5wXaysbQZVtZYO-r/view?usp=share_link>

y = np.arange(0,150,1)

y_interp = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

y_interp(0)
```

The result is:

```
array(112.72889837)
```

But it also passes by ~50.

Comment: Are you sure you want your data to be on the x-axis and not the y-axis?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: Hi, @Dash. you could change x-axis by y-axis. The result is the most important. I found a way, using this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843017/efficiently-detect-sign-changes-in-python. But, I do not know if it is OK.