# counting string switches in a list with groupby

Tags: python, string, python-itertools

I have a headache and dictionary like this:

```
{a: ['+','+','-','-','+','-','-','+'],
b: ['+','+','+','-','-','+','+','+','-'],
c: ['-','-','-','+','+','+']}
```

And I want to know how many times the string of values change, something like this:

```
a = 4
b = 3
c = 1
```

I have tried using groupby from itertools, by doing this:

```
for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
    print k + ' ' + str([len(list(g[1])) for g in groupby(list(v)) if g[0] =='+'])
```

But I get only a list containing two values (two string switches)..
I have tried changing the '+' and '-' characters without success, any recommendations?

Comment: You can code your own loop akin to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2936861/1317713
Instead of remembering the sign, remember the last value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something you could do is build a dictionary using a dictionary comprehension and count how many times the values in each entry in the dictionary change:

```
d = {'a': ['+','+','-','-','+','-','-','+'], 'b': ['+','+','+','-','-','+','+','+','-'], 
     'c': ['-','-','-','+','+','+']}

s = {k : sum(1 for i,j in zip(d[k][1:], d[k][:-1]) if i != j) for k in d}
# {'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 1}
```

Or if you prefer [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
{k : sum(1 for i in groupby(d[k]))-1 for k in d}
# {'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 1}
```

---

**Details**

In order to detect a change in the elements in each list, you can compare its elements with a lagged version of the list, which can be done by zipping two slices of the list, `zip(d[k][1:], d[k][:-1])`.

For instance, for key `a`:

```
list(zip(d['a'][1:], d['a'][:-1]))
# [('+', '+'), ('-', '+'), ('-', '-'), ('+', '-'), ('-', '+'), ('-', '-'), ('+', '-')]
```

Now simply use a generator expression and add `1` each time the values in a tuple are different:

```
sum(1 for i,j in zip(d['a'][1:], d['a'][:-1]) if i != j)
# 4
```

Comment: As a note to OP, the `d[k][1:], d[k][:-1]` offsets the two lists by one so you can do an element-wise comparison rather than storing the last value and checking

Comment: amazing yatu, thank you, have upvoted but I get some message about new user`s votes are not visualized or something like that.

Comment: @fcalles you can also upvote now with your rep :-) (thanks for accepting!)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to filter. Just count the groupby:

```
mydict = {'a': ['+','+','-','-','+','-','-','+'],
'b': ['+','+','+','-','-','+','+','+','-'],
'c': ['-','-','-','+','+','+']}

for k,v in mydict.items():
  print(k + ' ' + str(len(list(itertools.groupby(list(v))))-1))
```

Comment: No need for `list(v)`