# Counting elements of an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, count, return-value

I've been searching the answer for an exercise.
This exercise gives us an array with numbers between -1 and 1.
We are asked to count how many times the signal array changes sign.
For example : you have this array :
[0.7,0.5,0.6,-0.1,0.9,0.6,0.4,-0.2,-0.3,0.2,0.3,-0.3,-0.9,-0.7,0.1,0.2]
It changes signs 7 times
This is the code I have made that should get the "count" of how many times it changes signs.
For some reason, it doesn't work, the count at the end is equal to 0 and it should be 7.
Can you help me please ?
Thank you very much.

--THE CODE--

```
import numpy as np

def zeroCrossing(signal):

    j=0
    ls=len(signal)
    print(ls)
    count=0
    x=0
    y=0
    for j in range(0,ls):
        if signal[j]>0 and x==1:
            j=j+1
            y=0
        elif signal[j]>0 and x==0:
            count==count+1
            x=1
            j=j+1
        elif signal[j]<0 and y==1:
            j=j+1
            x=0
        elif signal[j]<0 and y==0:
            count==count+1
            y=1
            j=j+1
    
    return count

print(zeroCrossing(np.array([0.7,0.5,0.6,-0.1,0.9,0.6,0.4,-0.2,-0.3,0.2,0.3,-0.3,-0.9,-0.7,0.1,0.2])))
```

Comment: It seems that you count the initial numbers as a "change" in sign?

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `count==count+1` to do?

Comment: The answer is 6, not 7, surely?

Comment: `arr = np.array([0.7,0.5,0.6,-0.1,0.9,0.6,0.4,-0.2,-0.3,0.2,0.3,-0.3,-0.9,-0.7,0.1,0.2]);
print(sum(np.where(np.sign(arr) != np.sign(np.roll(arr, -1)), 1, 0)))` would do it, but I don't get where the 7 comes from

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - counting sign changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936834/python-counting-sign-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not modifying `count` variable, because you use comparison operator instead of assignment. Replace `count==count+1` by `count=count+1` to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want simply by iterating through the array as follows:

```
sign_changes = 0
last_number = None
for n in my_array:
    if n < 0: # checks if n is negative
        if last_number != "negative": # checks if the last number was not negative
            sign_changes += 1
        last_number = "negative"
    else: # takes n as positive (including 0)
        if last_number != "positive": # checks if the last number was not positive
            sign_changes += 1
        last_number = "positive"
```

Edit:

This code will count 7 in the example array given by the OP, as the OP expects, which counts the first number as a "sign change". To avoid this (and instead count 6 sign changes), small tweaks to the code can be made. The most simple is to change the `last_number != "positive"` and `last_number != "negative"` conditions to `last_number == "negative"` and `last_number == "positive"` respectively.

Comment: If they are going to use arrays then this is hopelessly slow

Comment: Whether or not it is "hopeless" depends on the exact aims of the script/program. This is a simple solution that works well and answers the question. The OP has not specified any high performance requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Since you always count the first number as 1 time, you may try this numpy code:

```
arr = np.array([0.7,0.5,0.6,-0.1,0.9,0.6,0.4,-0.2,-0.3,0.2,0.3,-0.3,-0.9,-0.7,0.1,0.2])
change_count = np.count_nonzero(np.diff(np.sign(arr))) + 1

Out[122]: 7
```